# Update flutter project to stable null-safety

Tags: flutter-dependencies, flutter

I'm trying to update my flutter project to flutter stable 2.0.3, but got the error:

Because every version of flutter_driver from sdk depends on webdriver 2.1.2 which depends on archive >=1.0.0 <3.0.0, every version of flutter_driver from sdk requires archive >=1.0.0 <3.0.0.

Does anyone know how to solve this? I tried to import the package webdriver version ^3.0.0, but when trying to run the app, I got the error:

Because every version of flutter_driver from sdk depends on webdriver 2.1.2 and app depends on webdriver ^3.0.0, flutter_driver from sdk is forbidden. So, because app depends on flutter_driver any from sdk, version solving failed. Running "flutter pub get" in app...
pub get failed (1; So, because app depends on flutter_driver any from sdk, version solving failed.)

Here's my pubscpec:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.5.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  auto_size_text: ^2.1.0 #https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text
  auto_orientation: ^1.0.5 #https://pub.dev/packages/auto_orientation
  cached_network_image: ^2.0.0 #https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cached_network_image#-installing-tab-
  carousel_slider: ^1.3.0 #https://github.com/serenader2014/flutter_carousel_slider
  connectivity: ^3.0.3 #https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity
  cpf_cnpj_validator: ^1.0.5 #https://github.com/leonardocaldas/flutter-cpf-cnpj-validator
  dots_indicator: ^1.0.0 #https://pub.dev/packages/dots_indicator
  image_picker: ^0.6.0+15 #https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image_picker
  flutter_cache_manager: ^3.0.1 #https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager
  flutter_full_pdf_viewer: ^1.0.6 #https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_full_pdf_viewer
  flutter_local_notifications: ^5.0.0 #https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications
  flutter_masked_text: ^0.8.0 #https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_masked_text
  flutter_slidable: ^0.5.4 #https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_slidable
  flutter_svg: ^0.18.0 #https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_svg#-installing-tab-
  flushbar: ^1.10.2 #https://pub.dev/packages/flushbar
  google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.20+6 #https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter
  http: ^0.13.0 #https://pub.dev/packages/http
  package_info: ^0.4.0+6 #https://pub.dev/packages/package_info
  path_provider: ^2.0.1 #https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider
  photo_view: ^0.4.0 #https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/photo_view#-installing-tab-
  provider: ^4.0.1 #https://pub.dev/packages/provider
  rate_my_app: ^0.7.2 #https://pub.dev/packages/rate_my_app
  rxdart: ^0.26.0 #https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/rxdart
  sendgrid_mailer: ^0.1.2 #https://pub.dev/packages/sendgrid_mailer
  share_extend: ^1.0.9 #https://pub.dev/packages/share_extend
  store_redirect: ^1.0.2 #https://pub.dev/packages/store_redirect
  url_launcher: ^5.2.5 #https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher
  webdriver: ^3.0.0

  # Firebase packages
  cloud_firestore: ^1.0.1
  firebase_core: ^1.0.1
  firebase_auth: ^1.0.1
  firebase_analytics: ^7.1.1
  cloud_functions: ^1.0.0
  firebase_storage: ^8.0.0
  firebase_crashlytics: ^1.0.0 #https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_crashlytics
  firebase_messaging: ^9.0.0 #https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  test: ^1.5.1
  flutter_driver:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  pedantic: null
```

Comment: each dependency is interdependent, you have to solve each by yourself, as per the errors you are getting,

Comment: Try using `any` keyword with packages having issue of dependencies. Otherwise you Have to figure this thing out yourself. E.g. `flutter_driver: any`

Comment: I already upgrade all the package versions that were giving errors, now I'm stuck at this error on webdriver, I wasn't using the webdriver package, just added to test.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, to solve this I had to override the dependecies, like this:

```
dependency_overrides:
  archive: ^3.1.2
  crypto: ^3.0.0
  xml: ^5.0.2
```